# SQLDependency OnChangeEvent not firing

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-2012, sqldependency

I have the following code to execute a SqlCommand against a database View:

```
public IEnumerable<PickNote> GetData()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BTNInternalData_LiveEntities"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [PICKINGROUTEID],[CUSTOMER],[SALESNAME]
           FROM [dbo].[PickScreenData] WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [ACTIVATIONDATETIME])) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) or [EXPEDITIONSTATUS] = 3", connection))
                {
                    // Make sure the command object does not already have
                    // a notification object associated with it.
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var data = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>();

                        return data.Select(x => new PickNote
                        {
                            pickingRouteId = x["PICKINGROUTEID"].ToString()
                        }).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

However, the `dependency_OnChange` method only gets called at the start of my application and doesn't do so again no matter if the data in my View changes. I've debugged SqlNotificationEventArgs and the Info is `Invalid` but I'm not sure why as the command query runs fine

### Edit

I've changed the query so that it queries the table directly but `SqlNotificationEventArgs.Info` still says `Invalid`. Here is the new code:

```
public IEnumerable<PickNote> GetData()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AXLive"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"
                SELECT PICKINGROUTEID, EXPEDITIONSTATUS
                FROM         [dbo].[WMSPICKINGROUTE]
                WHERE     (EXPEDITIONSTATUS <> 20) 
                AND (DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [ACTIVATIONDATETIME])) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
                    OR [EXPEDITIONSTATUS] = 3)", connection))
            {
                // Make sure the command object does not already have
                // a notification object associated with it.
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var data = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>();

                    return data.Select(x => new PickNote
                    {
                        pickingRouteId = x["PICKINGROUTEID"].ToString()
                    }).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`WMSPICKINGROUTE` is the table where my view was getting the data from before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx), you cannot use a SqlDependency against a select statement that references a view. That seems to be the problem. Rewrite your query to hit tables and it should work.

Comment: I've changed it so that it queries the table directly but it still says invalid in `SqlNotificationEventArgs.Info`

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff I don't have much personal experience with notifications, but I'd suggest starting with a very simple select statement with no where criteria and see if that behaves as you'd expect. Make sure you are meeting all the other criteria referenced on that MSDN pae.

Comment: That's what I did, I took out the Date stuff from the WHERE clause and it worked. @ledbutter

Comment: Ah, that's what I was alluding to: the calculated date stuff in your where clause. Sure seems like this dependency stuff has limited use.

Comment: Yeah it seems quite limited but its still very good when its impossible to use other means :)